# Сравнение максимальных элементов двух массивов

Tags: java

Всем привет. Запутался в сравнении массивов.

Первая строка ввода содержит N - количество компаний.
Вторая строка содержит годовые доходы каждой компании. Все числа являются неотрицательными целыми числами.
Третья строка содержит индивидуальные налоги для каждой компании в процентах от дохода компании. Все числа являются целыми числами от 0 до 100 включительно.

Вывести № компании, которая платит больше всего налогов. Помните, что перечень компаний начинается с номера 1. Если существует несколько компаний с одинаковыми размерами платежей, выведите номер компании с наименьшим номером.

Пример ввода:

2

50 100

10 10

Пример вывода:

2

Пример ввода 2:

3

50 100 300

100 20 0

Пример вывода 2:

1

```
public class IndividualTaxes {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int size = scanner.nextInt(); 
        int[] incomes = new int[size]; 
        for (int i = 0; i < incomes.length; i++) {
            incomes[i] = scanner.nextInt();
        }
        int[] percents = new int[size]; 
        for (int i = 0; i < percents.length; i++) {
            percents[i] = scanner.nextInt();
        }
        int max1 = 0;
        int max_index1 = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < incomes.length; i++) {
            if (percents[i] > max1) {
                max1 = percents[i];
                max_index1 = i;
            }
        }

        int max2 = 0;
        int max_index2 = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < percents.length; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < percents.length; ++j) {
                if (percents[i] > max2) {
                    max2 = percents[i];
                    max_index2 = i;
                    {
                        if (percents[j] > max2) {
                            max2 = percents[j];
                            max_index2 = j;
                        }
                    }
                    if (percents[i] == percents[j]) {
                        System.out.println(max_index1 + 1);
                        break;
                    } else {
                        System.out.println(max_index2 + 1);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте реализовать данные структурой...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
double maxTax = 0;
int maxTaxIdx = -1; 
for (int i = 0; i < incomes.length; i++) {
  double tax = incomes[i] * percents[i];
  if (i == 0) {
    maxTax = tax;
    maxTaxIdx = 0;
  } else if (tax > maxTax) {
    maxtTax = tax;
    maxTaxInd = i;
  }
}
System.out.println(maxTaxInd + 1);
```